# Adding 'activeClassName' to NavLink in React Router

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, react-router

Ok, so i have this component, it's render well, but i have problem, when route changing, the activeClassName doesn't change dynamically - 
I need to refreshing page.

**Target behaviour**: change **activeClass** dynamically - without refreshing the page.

---

[image]

```
                  <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="activeRoute" exact={true} ><img src ={MobileIcon1}/><p>MAIN</p></NavLink>
                  <NavLink to="/cprojects" activeClassName="activeRoute"><img src ={MobileIcon2}/><p>PROJECTS</p></NavLink>
                  <NavLink to="/cabout" activeClassName="activeRoute"><img src ={MobileIcon3}/><p>ABOUT</p></NavLink>
                  <NavLink to="/articles" sactiveClassName="activeRoute"><img src ={MobileIcon4}/><p>ARTICLES</p></NavLink>
```

---

Ok i refactored code, and it's works for now - the problem was in nesting the component and not connecting it to **withRouter**

Comment: You want the classname to be dynamic?

Comment: the Navlink element should change after route change dynamically

Comment: Your code should work, does it brings you to the correct page?

Comment: Try adding this const 
activeStyle = { color: "#F15B2A" }; 

and inside the navlink try adding 
  activeStyle={activeStyle}

Comment: It apply styles - but when i changing route nothing change.

Comment: You can also trey exporting your component with ```withRouter``` function.
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; and then: export default withRouter(ProgrammerMobileMenu);

Comment: I adding withRouter and it's still doesn't work